# Is this possible to compare two JSON arrays and get their diffrence in result in karate framework?

Tags: json, automated-tests, karate

I am using **match each** it compares each element but I need the difference of those two.
Like

```
def data1 = { foo: [{ bar: 1, baz: 'a' }, { bar: 2, baz: 'b' }, { bar: 3, baz: 'c' }]}

def data2 = { foo: [{ bar: 4, baz: 'x' }, { bar: 2, baz: 'b' }, { bar: 3, baz: 'c' }]}
```

then I only need

```
 { foo: [{ bar: 1, baz: 'a' },{ bar: 4, baz: 'x' }]}
```

Not the elements which got matched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will collect the positions of mismatched elements, try `print indexes` at the end:

```
* def data1 = [{ bar: 1, baz: 'a' }, { bar: 2, baz: 'b' }, { bar: 3, baz: 'c' }]
* def data2 = [{ bar: 4, baz: 'x' }, { bar: 2, baz: 'b' }, { bar: 3, baz: 'c' }]
* def indexes = []
* def fun = 
"""
function(x, i) {
  var result = karate.match(data1[i], data2[i]);
  if (!result.pass) karate.appendTo(indexes, i);
}
"""
* karate.forEach(data1, fun)
```

I also think you are mis-using Karate, maybe you should just write code or use some other framework. You don't seem to be doing testing.

Comment: Thanks for this example. I think this is very helpful. I would add "karate.log ("Mismatch: ", data1[i], data2[i])" inside the "if" of the function. When a test fails, I as a developer, HAVE to know why it failed - as I have to fix it. This approach tells me very quickly why it failed (if it fails) - instead of me having to debug / dig thru code. If it works - no harm / no foul - nothing gets printed. E.g. Many IDEs for supporting JUnit, showing exactly where a string does not match with the expected string. Which is very helpful. Groovy spock framework does the same. Very helpful.

Comment: @AriSingh you really need to try the new RC version: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide

Comment: Thanks. Looks very cool. Especially https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide#improved-error-details-for-match-failures - exactly what I was talking about.